# Apache2 как присвоить сайту порт

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

Хотел узнать возможно ли присвоить сайту определённый порт.
Например есть два сайта - example.com и chat.example.com .
И как сделать чтобы сайт example.com работал на порту 80 , а chat.examle.com работал на 81.
Ubuntu : 16.04 LTS 
PHP: 7.0

Comment: [Apache VirtualHost Examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)

Comment: есть подозрение, что вы спрашиваете не совсем о том, чего бы вам хотелось добиться. изложите, пожалуйста, чуть подробнее, **для чего** вы хотите сделать описанное. прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]